# Let's say someone creates a dragon

Tags: science-based, magic, dragons

Would the laws of science allow this being to exist? A four-legged, two-winged dragon (and able to fly, obviously), he doesn't need to breathe fire or anything, just be large (at least the size of a horse), reptilian and mostly carnivorous.

I know evolution would not favor these beings to come into being, but if they were created artificially, could they live and fly according to science? Even if they don't breathe fire.

Comment: Oops, it appears I've accidentally used my super-powers and smote your question. Whilst I do feel that this question has been adequately answered elsewhere, I'm not 100% certain that this is the definitive match for your question. I'll see if I can get a mod to undo the closure.

Comment: Guys, my question is yes-no (giving additional explanations if necessary, of course) and not one of "how it would be" nor "what would it take for this to be possible".

Comment: Honestly your main problem here is the "for legged" part. If you're fine with them being just horse sized, somewhat reptilian, able to fly and mostly carnivorous, you're set, so long as you don't mind having tail-less, stork-looking giraffe sized wyverns.

Comment: Yes/no questions are not best fit for the way we work, why not try and ask something that's likely to generate a more involved, interesting and useful answer, just a thought. I believe a reading of Monty Wild's detailed answer addresses everything here, if you feel it doesn't then please [edit] to tell us why.

Comment: Mas se eu fizer uma pergunta de "como", minha postagem vai ser fechada de novo como duplicata. Quantas perguntas já não têm nesse site de "como seria um dragão realista?" ou "como um dragão voaria?", hein? Eu só não pergunto em outros sites porque esse me deu a sensação de ter mais gente especializada em coisas do gênero em que se pode fazer perguntas publicamente, além de ter me dado a sensação de parecer ser o melhor.

Comment: Olha cara, é triste, mas é assim. Pesquisar sobre pterosauros do gênero "ahzdarchidae" é a melhor opção pro seu caso. Quanto maior o dragão, mais pesado ele fica e mais difícil é voar, e você tem o problema extra de ter um par a mais de membros pesando a coisa toda (pterosauros gigantes tinham adaptações extremas pra eliminar qualquer pezinho "desnecessauro", por isso eles podiam crescer).

Answer (score 1):

The main problem would be getting airborne as an animal the size and mass of a horse could not fly properly. It might be able to glide down from a cliff, but that would be about it and it would have to walk back to the top.

Comment: _Quetzalcoatlus_ may have managed OK, but it wasn't shaped much like any kind of traditional dragon.

Comment: Quetzalcoatlus at 200-250kg could perhaps glide and soar, but a horse is more like 380-1000kg and a flying animal of that weight would be more likely to swoop and plunge.

Comment: The OP did mention _size_ of a horse rather than mass, FWIW.

Comment: Fair point. If it's appearance only then a fairly large dragon shaped skin and bone gasbag should work.

Comment: [Something like this mght do.](https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.BSIm6c--VuqzEKNpuxl7fAHaHa?pid=ImgDet&rs=1).